# Return empty where criteria does not match

Tags: postgresql

I have the following PGSQL statement that's meant to return all the items from multiple checklists

```
SELECT 
    cl.id as checklist_id,
    ci.id checklist_item_id,
    ci.name,
    ci.details,
    cil.id as logid,
    cil.date_added,
    cs.id as schedule_id,
    a.id as account_id, a.first_name || ' ' || a.last_name as full_name
FROM checklist_item ci
    LEFT JOIN checklist cl ON cl.id = ci.checklist_id
    LEFT JOIN checklist_item_log cil ON cil.checklist_item_id = ci.id
    LEFT JOIN checklist_schedule cs ON cs.id = cil.checklist_schedule_id
    LEFT JOIN account a ON a.id = cil.account_id
--WHERE cil.date_added >= now()::date + interval '1h' OR cil.date_added is null
GROUP BY cl.id, ci.id, cil.id, cs.id, a.id
```

The commented out `WHERE` clause should only select items where the date is today OR null. 
[image]

While this functionality is fine, I need it to also include items from previous dates, but as an empty result.

[image]

In the case of the result above, `[3] chairs` should return with null results in the `checklist_item_log` table. Is this possible?

Let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: Add your condition in the left joins section, not in where. Try it.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN checklist_item_log cil ON cil.checklist_item_id = ci.id AND cil.date_added >= now()::date + interval '1h' OR cil.date_added is null`

Oh

Comment: Don't forget to add parenthesis since you have an OR `LEFT JOIN checklist_item_log cil ON cil.checklist_item_id = ci.id AND (cil.date_added >= now()::date + interval '1h' OR cil.date_added is null)`

Comment: See if it work fine then I will add it as an answer.

Comment: @JorgeCampos This works as I need it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments your solution would be:

```
SELECT 
    cl.id as checklist_id,
    ci.id checklist_item_id,
    ci.name,
    ci.details,
    cil.id as logid,
    cil.date_added,
    cs.id as schedule_id,
    a.id as account_id, a.first_name || ' ' || a.last_name as full_name
FROM checklist_item ci
    LEFT JOIN checklist cl ON cl.id = ci.checklist_id
    LEFT JOIN checklist_item_log cil ON cil.checklist_item_id = ci.id
    LEFT JOIN checklist_schedule cs ON cs.id = cil.checklist_schedule_id
    LEFT JOIN account a ON a.id = cil.account_id
                           AND (cil.date_added >= now()::date + interval '1h' 
                                OR cil.date_added is null)
GROUP BY cl.id, ci.id, cil.id, cs.id, a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two queries, one as above, and one that selects only the old ones like you describe above.

Then write `UNION ALL` between the queries to combine them to a single query.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/460557/jorge-campos gave me the answer, without having to write two queries